# Why does the color after Image.Clear(x) not exactly equal the color x?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, xunit.net, system.drawing.color

The sample code for this issue is largely self-explanatory, so:

```
[Fact]
private void Color_in_should_equal_color_out()
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(128,128,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);   
    var color = Color.FromArgb(30,60,90,120);         
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.Clear(color);
    }

    var result = bitmap.GetPixel(0,0);

    Assert.Equal(color, result);
}
```

In this instance I would expect the color of the background to be identical to the color I cleared it to. Instead I get this:

```
Assert.Equal() Failure 

Expected: Color [A=30, R=60, G=90, B=120]
Actual:   Color [A=30, R=59, G=93, B=119]
```

How is this even possible?

Some pass:

```
Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

Some more examples that fail:

```
Expected: Color [A=32, R=64, G=96, B=128]
Actual:   Color [A=32, R=63, G=95, B=127]

Expected: Color [A=128, R=192, G=32, B=16]
Actual:   Color [A=128, R=191, G=31, B=15]

Expected: Color [A=32, R=192, G=127, B=90]
Actual:   Color [A=32, R=191, G=127, B=87]
```

Comment: PS: I have searched and don't think this is a duplicate, closest matches I could find are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721324/using-toargb-followed-by-fromargb-does-not-result-in-the-original-color and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032398/why-does-color-isnamedcolor-not-work-when-i-create-a-color-using-color-fromargb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@redwyre's comment is correct (but I don't have sufficient reputation myself to comment).  So I'll refer you to Vincent Povirk's comment at [Drawing PixelFormat32bppPARGB images with GDI+ uses conventional formula instead of premultiplied one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809506/drawing-pixelformat32bpppargb-images-with-gdi-uses-conventional-formula-instead):

> The format of your foreground image doesn't matter (given that it has alpha) because you're setting it to a Gdiplus::Color. Color values are defined as non-premultiplied, so gdiplus multiplies the components by the alpha value when it clears the foreground image. The alternative would be for Color values to have different meaning depending on the format of the render target, and that way lies madness.

The example in that post uses Gdiplus directly, but then, so does System.Drawing.Graphics, as you can see [here](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs#1923) in the .NET sources.

The different values you see are directly related to round-tripping from color channel value to premultiplied value and back using 8-bit arithmetic.  (E.g., from your last example, alpha=32 and B=90: 90*32/255 = 11.2+ truncates to 11 then back 11*255/32 = 87.6+ truncates to 87.)

Comment: I tried both PixelFormat32bppPArgb and PixelFormat32bppArgb and they produced the same result (as did 64bit PArgb etc for that matter). I would not expect *both* pre- an post-calculated alpha to produce the exact same rounding errors, otherwise what's the point of premultiplying the alpha channel at all?

Comment: Also using the main example above (with `[A=30, R=60, G=90, B=120]`) how can G possibly end up as 93? For the 90->87 example you highlighted to work it has to be rounding 11.2 towards zero. For the 90->93 example it only works if rounding 10.5 away from zero (and even then should be 94 not 93). It's the inconsistency of results that has me thinking 'bug' as a possibility.

Comment: @nathanchere - The 90->93 example works too because the results are rounded. I said truncated above because that was the case for that example, but the arithmetic is really rounding.  The 94 vs 93 issue is standard for computer arithmetic which doesn't always round the way we learned in school (that .5 rounds up, for example).  In fact, computer arithmetic frequently rounds toward 0.  Also in fact, different instructions on the same architecture may round differently, e.g., regular instructions in general registers vs SIMD instructions in SIMD registers (like SSE).

Comment: @nathanchere - W.r.t. your question about the use of xPArgb vs xArgb - there's remarkably little on the net about GDI+ internals.  I have seen lots of hints that the native internal format it uses is always premultiplied alpha, though it will manipulate bitmaps in other native formats if handed them (e.g., if you create a GDI bitmap with a specific pixel format and then pass its handle to GDI+).  With that in mind, it seems that the pixel formats you specify are sometimes not the internal representation, but merely the I/O representation it will use if you, e.g., hand it an array of bytes.